# Is there a general form for $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form, nested-radicals

Can I find the general term of this sequence $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$, $a_1=\sqrt2$? I have proved the convergence. And found its limit. But is there any general form for it?

Comment: can you prove it?

Comment: @6005 That's a pretty strong comment to make. You would have to back this up, even with empirical evidence (if proving is too hard, at least support your statements with something). [But the answer below seems to hint that you'd have a hard time doing so.]

Comment: See also: [Proof of an equality involving cosine $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}\ =\ 2\cos (\pi/2^{n+1})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/649968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  If $a_n=2 \cos(\theta_n)$ with $0 < \theta_n<\pi/2$, then:

$\sqrt{2+a_n}=\sqrt{2+2 \cos(\theta_n)}$

$=2 \sqrt{(1+\cos(\theta_n))/2}$

$=2 \cos((\theta_n)/2)$ using the appropriate half-angle formula.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. The formula is
$$a_n=2\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}.$$
The proof is by induction on $n$, and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: wow. How did you get there?

Comment: @DenisNichita I'll risk an answer: by memory.

Comment: Experience :-) The recurrence formula (appropriately scaled) is a perfect match with the angle halving formula for cosine. I'm sure the details have been covered many times on our site. Hence CW.

Comment: Is there any rigorous proof? I don't think you just based this answer by intuition....

Comment: Well, once you have this guess, you can prove it by induction, as stated. Hard to find, easy to verify.

Comment: The same trick worked also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/334796/11619).